# How to have Nullable T as return type?

Tags: c#, generics, enums, nullable

I have a method that I use to convert strings to generic enums. The resulting value can be assigned to fields that *may* be nullable.

For the non-nullable case the following works fine, but I can't figure out how to correctly adjust it to allow for a nullable return type, say in the case that the argument is null, or indeed how to allow for a return type that may be either null or non-nullable (maybe this isn't possible?). Every permutation of `Nullable<T>` and `T?` that I've tried still results in red squiggleys on both the return values and the method name

```
private static T ConvertStringToEnumValue<T>(string value)
{
    // Converts string to a given enum-type T value.
    T EnumValue;
    try
    {
        EnumValue = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), EnumValue))
        {
            return default(T); // 0 for enum
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return default(T); // 0 for enum
    }
    return EnumValue;
}
```

Comment: "red squiggleys" - those are compilation errors: if you hover over them, you will see an explanation of why the compiler isn't happy.

Comment: @AntP heh, yeah thanks, I know :-). I tried many permutations and so had many different errors - not much point in reproducing each permutation here with the individual errors for each

Comment: there was a close vote that moved to "constrain T to Enum"; I have overridden that, because that is not what the question asks

Comment: "not much point in reproducing each permutation here with the individual errors for each": I disagree - it's worth at least showing *some* permutations (the ones you think have the most promise). Otherwise it's very hard to explain concrete errors...

Comment: If you only want to return null, you can use "return default(T);"

Comment: @Marc yeah I was about to undo that as I re-read the question, but thanks.

Comment: @SeanStayn that results in `Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'T?'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`. Using `default(T?)` results in `The type 'T' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as a parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<t>'`

Comment: @Toby I mean it like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r8hYBZ

Comment: Anyway I have to agree with what AntP and Jon say. If your question is about how you actually call this method, then show how you call it, including the errors. I mean: I can't reproduce any error, and it just works as-is: http://ideone.com/GLtNJO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
private static Nullable<T> ConvertStringToEnumValue<T>(string value) where T : struct
```

Or you can use this:

```
private static T? ConvertStringToEnumValue<T>(string value) where T : struct
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman : Yes I know. But I just wanted to show that both where possible when adding the T : struct

Comment: Is there a difference between `Nullable<T>` and `T?` at the return type?

Comment: No, it is just syntactic sugar. It compiles to the exact same code @Toby

Answer (score 6):

There is no type parameter constraint that allows 'types than can be null'. `T?` as return type is forbidden, and none of the constraints (`class`, `new()`, etc.) are helpful here.

You have to make two methods, and one of them you have to decorate with the `struct` constaint to allow `Nullable<T>`:

```
private static T? ConvertStringToEnumValue<T>(string value) where T : struct
```

Comment: Note that you should change the method name. You cannot have two methods where the only difference is the return type or the constraints.